# Removing Duplicate rows in 1 transaction ID while retaining other transaction item

Tags: sql

I have records like this :
**Trans_ID ITEM_NAME TOTAL_TRANS**
101 
                 
a 
                         
5
101                 
a
                         5
101                  b                           5
101                  c                           5
101                  b                           5
102                  a                           3
102                  c                           3
102                  c                           3

etc (aprox 270k record)

what query should i use to make it like this :

**Trans_ID ITEM_NAME    VALUE  TOTAL_TRANS**
101                   
a                  2/5                    5
101                  
b                  2/5                    5
101                  
c                  1/5                    5
102                  
a                  1/3                    3
102                  
c                  2/3                    3

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
`Trans_ID`, 
`ITEM_NAME`, 
CONCAT(count(*), '/', `TOTAL_TRANS`) AS VALUE, 
`TOTAL_TRANS` 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY `ITEM_NAME`, `Trans_ID`, `TOTAL_TRANS`
```

Comment: thx :D  
I modified your code into :   
SELECT    
`Trans_ID`,    
`ITEM_NAME`,  
count(*)/TOTAL_TRANS AS VALUE,  
`TOTAL_TRANS` 
FROM mytable    
GROUP BY `ITEM_NAME`, `Trans_ID`, `TOTAL_TRANS`  
since it's a numerical (my bad i forgot to give data type :()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT Trans_ID, ITEM_NAME,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(TOTAL_TRANS AS VARCHAR) AS VALUE,
    TOTAL_TRANS
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Trans_ID, ITEM_NAME, TOTAL_TRANS
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about your column data types, but this works for the sample data you provided.

```
SELECT Trans_ID, ITEM_NAME, 
    convert(varchar(5), count(*)) + '/' + convert(varchar(5), TOTAL_TRANS) as [VALUE], 
    TOTAL_TRANS
FROM Trans
GROUP BY Trans_ID, ITEM_NAME, TOTAL_TRANS
```